# Live graph with ultrasonic sensor on arduino and matplotlib pyqt to show graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino, pyqt5

I stuck on my code.  I want to have GUI on PyQt5 to show my graph. I have working code in matplot, but I cannot transform it to PyQT. I'm a beginner at this. I tried to find working similar code but I only did this. This works on matplotlib, but i want to have it on my GUI.

```
import serial
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *

distance =[]
arduinoData=serial.Serial('COM4',115200)
plt.ion()
cnt=0

def makeFig():
    plt.ylim(2,20)                         
    plt.title('Plot ')      
    plt.grid(True)                                 
    plt.ylabel('Distance cm')                            
    plt.plot(distance, 'ro-', label='Distance ')      
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')                   

while True: # While loop that loops forever
    while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0): #Wait here until there is data
        pass #do nothing
    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline() #read the line of text from the serial port
    measurement = int(arduinoString)           #Convert first element to floating number and put in measurement           
    distance.append(measurement)                     #Build our distance array by appending temp readings                 
    drawnow(makeFig)                       #Call drawnow to update our live graph
    plt.pause(.000001)                     #Pause Briefly. Important to keep drawnow from crashing
    cnt=cnt+1
    if(cnt>50):                            #If you have 50 or more points, delete the first one from the array
        distance.pop(0)                       #This allows us to just see the last 50 data points
                         #This allows us to just see the last 50 data points
```

My PyQt and Matplot.  I want to click on the button and show this graph.
I got  error that " in line 51, in plot
    measurement=int(arduinoString)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\n' " and 
"Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on."
I'm sending data that are simple distance like 5, 10 and so on from my sensor.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random
import serial
import numpy
from drawnow import *


arduinoData=serial.Serial('COM4',115200)

cnt=0
distance =[]
class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # a figure instance to plot on
        self.figure = plt.figure()

        # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
        # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init__
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        # this is the Navigation widget
        # it takes the Canvas widget and a parent
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        # Just some button connected to `plot` method
        self.button = QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)

        # set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def plot(self):
        while True:
            while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0): #wait for data 
                pass 

            arduinoString=arduinoData.readline() #read the line of text from the serial port

            measurement=int(arduinoString)
            distance.append(measurement)

            plt.pause(0.00001)
            global cnt
            cnt=cnt+1
            if (cnt>50):
                distance.pop(0)


        self.figure.clear()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        ax.plot(distance, '*-')

        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True: # While loop that loops forever
    while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0): #Wait here until there is data
        pass #do nothing
```

This doesn't actually wait, it executes whatever's below it regardless of your condition check. Try it as follows:

```
while True:
    if (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        continue
    #rest of your code
```

Comment: Now i dont have that error, but I still dont get any data to plot. and it open new matplotlib figure, not on one I have.  You can see what i mean in this picture
https://ibb.co/nx39zJ.

Comment: I tabbed last 4 lines in def plot, but I still have 2 same plot, how can I remove one of them? And new is responsible for showing changes, the old one just copy it, so when i close new version, old isnt working.